# capistrano deployment shell script fails when executed through github webhook

Tags: shell, github, capistrano, webhooks, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to implement a continuous deployment routine using github webhooks and capistrano.

My plan is to put my capistrano rake task in a shell script and call it from a controller action in another rails project which is the github webhook.

Here is the shell script (wallet_deploy.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $HOME/work/wallet
bundle exec cap production deploy > wallet_deploy_log 2>&1
```

Here is the log

```
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:304:in `block in replace_gem': capistrano is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/bin/cap:22:in `<main>'
```

Here is the controller action

```
def release_request
  system("./wallet_deploy.sh")
  #DeployWorker.perform_async // tried using a worker too with no success

  render :text => params.to_s
end
```

Cap deployment works perfectly when i execute it manually in the shell

```
deploy@ubuntu14-public:~/apps/ci/current$ ./wallet_deploy.sh
```

Not sure what i'm doing wrong and is there different approach to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Your Rails app that is listening for the webhook already has its own Bundler environment. When you try to shell out to your script using `system`, the script inherits that current Bundler environment. This is probably why you are getting a "capistrano is not part of the bundle" error.

To ensure a fresh Bundler environment is used for your script, try this:

```
Bundler.with_clean_env do
  system("./wallet_deploy.sh")
end
```

From Bundler's `bundle exec` [documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.12/man/bundle-exec.1.html):

> Any Ruby code that opens a subshell (like system, backticks, or %x{}) will automatically use the current Bundler environment. If you need to shell out to a Ruby command that is not part of your current bundle, use the with_clean_env method with a block.

And:

> Using with_clean_env is also necessary if you are shelling out to a different bundle. Any Bundler commands run in a subshell will inherit the current Gemfile, so commands that need to run in the context of a different bundle also need to use with_clean_env.